# how to add textfield in tableview cell(each row) and set tag to each textfield to access it's text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

How can i add textfield in tableview cell (on each row).
This textfield will be in middle of each row.
And also set Tag on each textfield of cell to access their text.

Comment: hi friends it's possible to add multiple textfield here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621732/how-to-add-textfield-in-tableview-cell-and-access-each-textfields-text-by-their?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can, a small example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"test"];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"test"] autorelease];

        UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (cell.contentView.bounds.size.height-30)/2, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tv];
        [tv setDelegate:self];
        tv.tag = indexPath.row;
    }

    return cell;
}

...
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSLog(@"%d", textView.tag);

    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
...
```

Comment: Hi friends, in my logic i have to add 12 textfield in tableview cell and access each textfield's text by their tag value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621732/how-to-add-textfield-in-tableview-cell-and-access-each-textfields-text-by-their